# Padding with a zero when reversing a number

Tags: c++

I am working on a program which has one function thats purpose is to reverse a three digit number. The code looks like

```
int reverseFunction(int userNumber){ 
    int reverse = 0,mod; 
    while (userNumber != 0)
    {
        mod = userNumber%10;
        reverse = reverse*10 + mod; 
        userNumber /= 10; 
    }

    return reverse;
}
```

This works great except when you pass it a number that has the first number only 1 greater than the last. The reverse is called later on and if the above is true you end up with a two digit number. e.g.

```
The number you entered is: 473.

The reversal of the input is: 374.

Subtraction of reversal from the original number is: 99.

Reversal of the resulting number is: 99.

Addition of the number to the un-reversed form is: 198.

The final outcome should be: 1089, which is our “Magic Number”.
```

If the '99' was padded with a zero '099' it would spit out 1089 which is the right number. How do I solve this problem and pad with a zero? I've seen ways to output with a zero but not to calculate with a zero. I'm using c++.

Comment: Just to clarify if you input 099 you want the reverse to be 990?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `reverse()` function. it would seem that the problem you are having is in another part of your code. Namely: in the code that adds a reversed number to it's original non-reversed form.

What you should do to make it behave the way you need is to first check if the number has 1, 2, or 3 digits and perform the addition accordingly.

For example:

```
int add(int _d, int _r){ // _d is "direct" and _r is "reversed" number
    int result = _d;
    if(_r > 99){ // 3 digits
      result += _r;
    }else if(_r > 9){ // only 2 digits
      result += _r * 10;
    }else{ // only 1 digit
      result += _r * 100;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your reverse function is general for numbers of all kinds of digits. So you should specify how many digits you want explicitly:

```
#include <math.h> 
int reverseFunction(int userNumber,int numOfDigits)
{ 
    int reverse = 0,mod; 
    int digitsCount = 0;
    while (userNumber != 0)
    {
        mod = userNumber%10;
        reverse = reverse*10 + mod; 
        userNumber /= 10; 
        digitsCount++;
    }
    return reverse*pow(10,numOfDigits-digitsCount);
}
```

This should do the padding thing for all kinds of digits now.

Comment: Doesn't look right to me. Have you tested that code?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.I was not. I changed a bit and it is working now: )